# Sowohl- als auch, nicht nur - sondern auch, weder - noch, entweder - oder(with two verbs)

Tags: usage

Can somebody give me examples of these connectors with two verbs? Two different activities!

> Ich höre sowohl Klassik als auch Pop.

Here there only one verb used. I would like to know if I could do two activities using two verbs at the same time.

> - Ich höre nicht nur Klassik, sondern auch Pop.
> - Sie hört weder Rock noch Jazz.
> - Er hört entweder Rock oder Techno.

In all these examples there is only a single type of verb which compliments the two objects. What if I want to say:

> I go to theatre as much I play cricket.

Or:

> I either watch a movie or I play cricket. I don't only watch cricket but also read books.

I hope it's a bit clear to you now.

---

My translation attempts:

> 1. Ich lese *sowohl* Bücher *als* ich *auch* Cricket spiele.
> 2. Ich esse *nicht nur* Pizza, *sondern* gehe ich *auch* ins Fitnessstudio.
> 3. Ich esse *weder* gesundes Essen *noch* gehe ich ins Fitnessstudio.
> 4. Ich bleibe *entweder* zu Hause, *oder* gehe ich ins Kino.

Not sure about the placements of colon.

Comment: ATM this looks like a homework (-like) question to me. Could you edit your question and add, what examples you find in standard dictionaries or simple internet search and why exactly those findings don't fit your expectations or what exactly you don't understand about their usage?

Comment: Ich höre sowohl Klassik als auch Pop. Here there is only one verb used. Would like to know if I could do two activities using two verbs at the same time. Ich höre nicht nur klassik, sondern auch Pop. Sie hört weder Rock noch Jazz. Er hört entweder Rock or Techno. In all these examples there only a single type of verb which compliments the two objects. What if I want to say. I go to theatre as much I play cricket. Or... I either watch a movie or I play cricket. I don't only watch cricket but also read books. I hope it's a bit clear to you now.

Comment: Yes, much better! Could you please edit your question and add your previous comment there? This will help people to help you.

Comment: Yes sure! Thanks! I'll do that right away. It was my first query ever so didn't figure it out until now! Thanks a lot

Comment: And regarding your question: it works similar as in English: you can use different verbs. Just try translating your examples!

Comment: Was just worried about the verb positions. Can't rely on translator for that. But I'll still see!

Comment: Now that you know how to edit: you can add your own your translation attempts and reword the question to ask, if the verb position is correct and about the rules behind it. Welcome on this site :)

Comment: Done :D will be easy to understand now

Answer (score 2):

> <s>Ich lese sowohl Bücher als ich auch Cricket spiele.</s>

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. *Sowohl … als auch …* does not accept finite verb forms. If you need verbs, you have to use infinitives or participles:

> Ich kann sowohl deutsche Texte gut lesen und schreiben als auch Hochdeutsch sprechen und verstehen.

These are four infinitives. The predicate is built from the modal verb *können* and those infinitives.

> Ich habe sowohl Bücher gelesen als auch Cricket gespielt.

These are two past participles. You can see you are limited to the perfect tenses (Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt, Futur II) here.

> Sowohl Bücher lesen als auch Cricket spielen tue ich.
>
> Ich verbringe meine Zeit sowohl Bücher lesend als auch Cricket spielend.

These are two ways to get around the infinitive/participle limitation in the other tenses.

---

> Ich esse nicht nur Pizza, sondern **ich** gehe <s>ich</s> auch ins Fitnessstudio.

*Nicht nur … sondern auch* connects two main clauses. That's why you need to follow the V2 word order in the second clause.

> Ich esse weder gesundes Essen **,** noch gehe ich ins Fitnessstudio.

Apart from the comma, that's correct. *Weder … noch …* also connects two main clauses but the **noch** isn't only a conjuction but an adverb too. It fills in first position.

> Ich bleibe entweder zu Hause, oder **ich** gehe <s>ich</s> ins Kino.

Same as with *nicht nur … sondern auch …*.

Comment: Oh this is beautiful. Right now I am studying B1 level. So, I still have to learn some of the tenses or the usage of a few. But you've cleared my doubt! Thanks a lot! I am sure I'll be apply these soon when I learn the other tenses.